# create canvas image from SVG image created with SVG.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I need to create a canvas image that will include one or more SVG images created using the SVG.js. 
To do this, the idea is to use the canvg library using the drawsvg function.
Each of the SVG images I would like to import, are composed by several png images on which for each of them has been applied several transformation (move, scale, rotations) done by SVG.js library.
Here the code; the svg_tag[0] is the original svg image I would like to transform as canvas object:

```
var svg_tag = $( "#" + shelf_id ).children("svg");
var dw = svg_tag.attr( "width" );
var dh = svg_tag.attr( "height" );
var id_svg = svg_tag.attr( "id" );

console.log(svg_tag[0].outerHTML);
console.log("getImage: shelf_id: " + shelf_id + " id_svg: " + id_svg + " dw: " + dw + " dh: " + dh);

$("#canvas").attr("width",dw + "px"); // set new canvas width
$("#canvas").attr("height",dh + "px"); // set new canvas height

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
//canvg(canvas, svg_tag[0].outerHTML)
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-drawimage
ctx.drawSvg(svg_tag[0].outerHTML, 0, 0, dw, dh); // it is printed only the shelf`
```

The canvas object anyway show only the first PNG image included inside the SVG image. Looking the console.log(svg_tag[0].outerHTML) , all other images of the SVG image has a width and height set to zero and the original transformation done by SVG.js are not there.

Using the debugger, this is the original SVG image created by SVG.js:

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1007" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="900" height="663" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image id="SvgjsImage1009" xlink:href="layout/PSS_16II_shelf.png" width="900" height="663"></image><image id="SvgjsImage1010" xlink:href="layout/8DG62445AA - IROADMV.png" width="1427" height="81" data-card_name="IROADMV" data-info="APN: 8DG62445AB node: MERKS_G-1-ON-1 linename: MERKS_G-1-ON-1@2 card_id: gui-59104" transform="scale(0.49614576033637003 0.4691358024691358) translate(98.76129943502825 554.2105263157895)"></image><image id="SvgjsImage1011" xlink:href="layout/8DG62445AA - IROADMV.png" width="1427" height="81" data-card_name="IROADMV" data-info="APN: 8DG62445AB node: MERKS_G-1-ON-1 linename: MERKS_G-1-ON-1@1 card_id: gui-59094" transform="scale(0.49614576033637003 0.4691358024691358) translate(98.76129943502825 645.8684210526316)"></image> ....  <defs id="SvgjsDefs1008"></defs></svg>
```

anyway the console.log show this one:

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1007" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="900" height="663" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image id="SvgjsImage1009" xlink:href="layout/PSS_16II_shelf.png" width="900" height="663"></image><image id="SvgjsImage1010" xlink:href="layout/8DG62445AA - IROADMV.png" width="0" height="0" data-card_name="IROADMV" data-info="APN: 8DG62445AB node: MERKS_G-1-ON-1 linename: MERKS_G-1-ON-1@2 card_id: gui-59104"></image><image id="SvgjsImage1011" xlink:href="layout/8DG62445AA - IROADMV.png" width="0" height="0" data-card_name="IROADMV" data-info="APN: 8DG62445AB node: MERKS_G-1-ON-1 linename: MERKS_G-1-ON-1@1 card_id: gui-59094"></image><image id="SvgjsImage1012" xlink:href="layout/WTOCM-F.png" width="0" height="0" data-card_name="WTOCM-F" data-info="APN: 8DG61330AA node: MERKS_G-1-ON-1 card_id: gui-59095"></image> ... <defs id="SvgjsDefs1008"></defs></svg></svg>
```

I have done a lot of tests without figure out where is the problem.
I have tried to clone the original svg node:

```
var copy = svg_tag[0].cloneNode(true);
```

without any result.
The only way to have it working is to manually copy-paste the original svg tag as showed above as string in the function:

```
canvg(canvas, '<svg id="SvgjsSvg1007"  ....   </svg>');
```

Which is the way to do using js, the below code doesn't work:

```
canvg(canvas, copy.outerHTML);
```

Thanks a lot. I have already spent more than half day without success.

Comment: I've checked the documentation for drawSvg canvg: `ctx.drawSvg(SVG_XML_OR_PATH_TO_SVG, dx, dy, dw, dh);` Why are you using `svg_tag[0].outerHTML` instead of `svg_tag[0]`?

Comment: The outerHTML is needed, otherwise you are passing the wrong object type; the canvg return error. Anyway, thanks to your question I have figure out where the problem was!! it was simply related to the fact, that I was creating the canvag object before the png images that compose the svg was completely loaded. Indeed, running the script from the debugger interface after the page is loaded works perfectly. Thanks again to your support. very appreciated. Thanks